# Retrieving values from backwards relationship as a list of integers instead of list of tuples?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

Right now I have a column named 'Value' in my 'Data' model, which has a ForeignKey from 'FOO' model:

```
class FOO(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
     ...

class Data(models.Model):
    label  = models.ForeignKey(Tickers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Volume = models.FloatField(default=0)
    ...
```

I'm fetching related objects as follows:

```
v = FOO.objects.get(pk='something')
vol = v.data_set.values_list('Volume')
```

and a get a list of tuples, which, afterwards, I have to convert to list integers with list comprehension.

Is there a more elegant way to get a list of integers directly?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with backwards relations. `values_list` takes a `flat=True` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I thought I'd give as much details as possible in the Title

Comment: Only to clarify, if `v` is an instance of `FOO class`,  to access to its related objects should be `v.data_set.values_list('Volume')` instead of `v.foo_set.values_list('Volume')`, it's right?

Comment: @AngelF Yes, thanks for pointing out! Silly typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the parameter `flat=True` e.g.:

```
vol = v.foo_set.values_list('Volume', flat=True)
```

For reference docs are at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list